# Difference between 讨厌, 恨, 怨恨, 忌恨, 恶, and 恼恨?

Tags: word-choice, difference

Could you please tell me the difference and how each word is used?

Comment: Just ignore the difference..Use any one when really hate..討厭is most common。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

讨厌：不喜欢，eg, 我讨厌夏天。我讨厌老鼠。

恨：范围太大了，有人多原因会产生恨，一种很激烈的对某人的负面情绪。

怨恨：重点是怨，因为怨气，一种强烈的多负面情绪，而恨某人

忌恨：重点是忌，因为嫉妒而心生恨意

恶：两种读音，è, 表示不好的，反义词是善。wù, 如厌恶，因为某种原因而讨厌某个人或物。

恼恨：重点在恼，因为恼怒而怨恨

I am not good at English，so I answer in Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

討厭: To dislike

恨: To hate

怨恨: To hate with discontent/grief, usually only to another person(s)

忌恨: To hate with envy, usually only to another person(s)

惡(wu): To dislike/loathe, usage is archaic

惱恨: To hate with anger (sometime to one's own regret/failure)